# Fetch the variable value by using ajax without post get method

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

here I have a shortcode that coontains input file type which I want to load a php file on .blur function.

// Where the input file is embedded

```
<input class="vh-radio-toggle" id="toggle8" type="radio" name="toggle" />
<label class="accordion-label" for="toggle8">I have an inspiration neon sign.</label> 
    <section id="content8"> 
    <label for="avatar">Send your inspirational custom neon logo image here:</label>
         <?php echo do_shortcode('[neon-inspire]');?>

    </section>
```

Here is the input file html. I just made it in shortcode.

```
function misha_uploader_callback(){
    return '<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="profilepicture" size="25" />
    <input type="text" name="neon_inspi" value="' . echo $neonInspi; .'">';
}
```

Here's my jquery ajax function.

```
jQuery("#neon-inspi").blur(function() { 
    var url = "http://localhost/neonew/wp-content/themes/twentytwenty/process_upload.php";
    jQuery.post(url, {} , function(data) {
        // The data here represents the answer from the server
        console.log("Data Loaded: " + data);
     });
});
```

Here's my process_upload.php. I want to load this php file by the .blur function . And I want to get the 
$neonInspi value to return to my input field below the input file html

```
<?php

// WordPress environment
require( dirname(__FILE__) . '/../../../wp-load.php' );

$wordpress_upload_dir = wp_upload_dir();
// $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] is the full server path to wp-content/uploads/2017/05, for multisite works good as well
// $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] the absolute URL to the same folder, actually we do not need it, just to show the link to file
$i = 1; // number of tries when the file with the same name is already exists

$profilepicture = $_FILES['profilepicture'];
$new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $profilepicture['name'];
$new_file_mime = mime_content_type( $profilepicture['tmp_name'] );

if( empty( $profilepicture ) )
    die( 'File is not selected.' );

if( $profilepicture['error'] )
    die( $profilepicture['error'] );

if( $profilepicture['size'] > wp_max_upload_size() )
    die( 'It is too large than expected.' );

if( !in_array( $new_file_mime, get_allowed_mime_types() ) )
    die( 'WordPress doesn\'t allow this type of uploads.' );

while( file_exists( $new_file_path ) ) {
    $i++;
    $new_file_path = $wordpress_upload_dir['path'] . '/' . $i . '_' . $profilepicture['name'];
}

// looks like everything is OK
if( move_uploaded_file( $profilepicture['tmp_name'], $new_file_path ) ) {


    $upload_id = wp_insert_attachment( array(
        'guid'           => $new_file_path, 
        'post_mime_type' => $new_file_mime,
        'post_title'     => preg_replace( '/\.[^.]+$/', '', $profilepicture['name'] ),
        'post_content'   => '',
        'post_status'    => 'inherit'
    ), $new_file_path );

    // wp_generate_attachment_metadata() won't work if you do not include this file
    require_once( ABSPATH . 'wp-admin/includes/image.php' );

    // Generate and save the attachment metas into the database
    wp_update_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, wp_generate_attachment_metadata( $upload_id, $new_file_path ) );

    // Show the uploaded file in browser
    // wp_redirect( $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $new_file_path ) );

    $neonInspi = $wordpress_upload_dir['url'] . '/' . basename( $new_file_path ) ;

}
```

Comment: input html edit
function misha_uploader_callback(){
    return '<input type="file" accept="image/png, image/jpeg" name="profilepicture" size="25" />
    <input type="text" name="neon_inspi" value="' . $neonInspi .'">';
}

Comment: what does `do_shortcode` do? where is `#neon-inspi`? when/where is `misha_uploader_callback` executed?